# LinkedIn API rate limit for OAuth based multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, linkedin-api

I just wanted to know is there any API rate limit for OAuth based LinkedIn authentication. Here we are fetching the user details like id,name..etc.

**Scenario**

**Consider,** 1000 + people are hitting my code to authenticate their LinkedIn account. Is there any rate limit.?

I'm doing below API calls using Node JS server.

```
 var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    var accessTokenOptions = {
            host: 'www.linkedin.com',
            path: '/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=' code + '&redirect_uri=' + callbackURL + '&client_id=' + appId + '&client_secret=' + appSecret,
            headers: headers
    };
    var linkedInUserDetailsHeaders = {
                'Authorization': bearerHeader
    };
    var linkedInUserDetailsOptions = {
            host: 'api.linkedin.com',
            path: '/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,picture-url,public-profile-url,email-address,date-of-birth)?format=json',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: linkedInUserDetailsHeaders
    };
```

By looking LinkedIn documentation, I got below details.

**LinkedIn :  500 / per day**

Is there any API rate limit per day basis to OAuth based authentication for multiple users. How could i support 1000 + people to access at the same time.

Comment: I know this is not really related to the question, but: are you a LinkedIn partner or were you approved for "Apply with LinkedIn"? I see that you are reading `date-of-birth` that is a `r_fullprofile` field. Unless you have additional access, it may stop working on May 12th.

Comment: Great Thanks. I'm not aware of additional profile field access stop working from May 12th on wards. What is an alternative for this. can you please share what we have to do make it work after these additional access after May 12 th.

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) to see the changes that will be made, and this [other](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/transition-faq) to see how to transition/create the app. But you may find someone here that knows better than me

Comment: Thanks for great help. Is there is no restriction to use r_basicprofile and 
r_emailaddress permission in LinkedIn App. Is i need to submit any thing to access these two permission ..?